# What is correct - "Take a look at it once" OR "Once take a look at it"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I want to frame a sentence telling someone to take a look at some work I did.

How do I frame the sentence?

> Please take a look at it once.

or

> Please once take a look at it.

To be clear - what I want is that the OP takes a look at my work at the very least; hence wanting to use the word "Once".

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically mean "Please take exactly one look at my work." I would go with

> Please take one look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Neither seems very likely to me - why ask them to only once? I suspect that you are wanting to persuade them to take a look, and reassure them that they won't need to more than once. In that case "Just take a look at it", or "Take a look at it just once" is more idiomatic.

If you do use "once" on its own, you first example is much more likely, partly because "once" can also function as a temporal conjunction ("Once you take a look at it, you'll see that ... "). This is not grammatical here, in an imperative construction, but to me the possibility of it makes "Please once take a look at it" difficult to parse.

Answer (score 0):

'Please take a look at it.' OR
'Please have a look at it.' 
Both sound right.
'Please take a look at it once' sounds awkward, and since much of good writing is also pleasing to the ears I would hesitate to use this option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use "at once" or "once," since it is implied when you say, "Please take a look at it." Adding "once" or "at once" would be redundant.

Comment: "At once" would be completely inconsistent with the OP's intended meaning, and the question never even mentioned the possibility of using that wording. The answer with respect to "once" is OK but that point has been made already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to signal your annoyance that they have yet to take a look at it, I think that adding "at least" would be the most common idiomatic way to do that:

```
Please, at least take a look at it.
```

Or:

```
Please take a look at it at least.
```

If you don't want to signal annoyance and want a more neutral, professional tone, then just go with:

```
Please take a look at it.
```

To take it a little further, I would also respectfully request a response:

```
Please take a look at it and let me know what you think.
```

Answer (score -1):

My first post here.

Please usually does the trick.  And flattery.  "You know all about this stuff, so could you take a look at..."

Where do I collect my change for the two cents?